# Updating Serialized value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to update a Serialized value on `meta_value` column on mysql table.But json is hard to select from sql . How can i achieve.

```
a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:19:"sevent_speaker_name";s:8:"John Doe";s:18:"sevent_speaker_img";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"72921";}}i:1;a:2:{s:19:"sevent_speaker_name";s:10:"John Smith";s:18:"sevent_speaker_img";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"72922";}}}
```

Here is the value. I want to replace all `sevent` with `elevent` but how can i do it?
Can I use `LIKE`? But first it need to be unserialized?.

[image]

Comment: This is an invalid json. A JSON can start with []  (array) or {} (object) only.

Comment: so what is this?

Comment: Referring to @AlanDeep, your value looks more like a serialized PHP object.

Comment: I agree with @BenRoob

Comment: @BenRoob Yes.I have updated question

Comment: You can do it from `MySQL` by using the `Replace()` function. Check this link: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

Answer (score 2):

This encoded information probably comes from WordPress or some other PHP framework's database; it's not JSON. Note that strings are encoded by storing the string length and the string contents:

```
s:19:"sevent_speaker_name"
```

You can use MySQL's `REPLACE` function to replace `sevent` with `elevent`, but you must be careful to update the length value `s` as well, or WordPress/PHP won't be able to read in the data.

It's possible to write a MySQL query to update the specific example given above, but it's difficult to write a query to substitutes all strings generically. Here is a [tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) that does the work.

Comment: yes its from wp.But i need to change.I can do it directly from mysql.But Could you please give an example??Coz I can use REPLACE and LIKE but its hesitating with serialized value

Comment: Have a look at the tool I've added to my answer.

Comment: According to the *"be aware of string length"*: would it not be easier to read your value with PHP (deserialize value), update the object and serialize it again, just to be safe? (I know it needs much more effort)

Comment: @BenRoob That would be a more elegant solution, but this tends to be a one-off thing you either do with search-and-replace in a SQL dump or with a tool.